# Common data between all pages?

Tags: web-part

We have several sub-sites under the root site. On every page, I'm trying to put my name on a WebPart as the contact information for the website. There should only be one place with my contact information stored. However, I don't have access to upload new webpart DLL's on the Sharepoint webserver. Can this sort of thing be done with a master page?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed content in a master page or pagelayout, but you cannot embed a web part since the implementation has to be on the actual page (i.e. where the settings are stored).  If you are just looking to identify the contact then that wouldn't be too bad.

Are you using WSS or MOSS?  Another approach would be to add the info at a top level site and then make it available throughout the site collection and show it in a DataView, CQWP, or custom display housed in a CEWP where no DLL would be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Data View Web Part (DVWP) to your master page which pulls information from a list.  I like this approach because then it becomes a content management task to change your name rather than a coding task.  I generally store "configuration" stuff like this in a list at the root of the Site Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Corasworks also makes a web part that does exactly what you are wanting to do. It keeps the content synced across pages with the same information. If you can afford a 3rd party tool, it may save you some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a simple task for a developer to create a custom control or delegate control that fetched the info from a list item. The control would then be placed in either master page or page layout (depending on where content is placed and how many places you would want this control.

hth
Anders Rask